# How should I set the version number between releases?

Tags: python, git, github, versioning

I have a Python project on GitHub ([ModelicaRes](https://github.com/kdavies4/ModelicaRes)).  I'm trying to follow [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/).  I post releases the main project site and upload them to PyPI.  For the releases, I write the version number in the main __init__.py file (`__version__=...`).  Between releases, I push updates to GitHub (usually on the main branch---nothing fancy).

How should I set the version number for these inter-release updates?  The commits are usually working copies.  They aren't fully tested, but others may download and use these copies (via GitHub).  Usually, I'm not ready to determine the new version number.  Lately I've been setting the version number to *None* and putting an auto-generated ["UNRELEASED COPY" file](https://github.com/kdavies4/ModelicaRes/blob/master/UNRELEASED%20COPY.md) in the base folder with the commit date and other info.  However, I'm not convinced this is the best approach.

This may apply to other languages, but right now I'm just interested in Python.

I guess I could try to use an "alpha", "beta", or "rc" suffix on the next version number, but again I don't always know the next version number (could be major or minor or bugfixes only).  I also want to keep this simple---not a lot of branching, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise. That being said, I'll give my opinion - until you make a release, keep `__version__` the same as the last release - it'll save you from having to change it every time you make a commit. Use `master` for your working branch, and upon release create a `release-x.y.z` branch. Or, have `release` and `master`. There are lots of ways to do it - see why this is primarily opinion-based?

Comment: @MattDMo: there may well be many ways of maintaining release numbers generally, but OP specifically said they were following SemVer, which has an absolutely unambiguous method: that's the whole point of it.

Comment: Yes, it'd be easiest to leave ``__version__`` the same as the last release, but I thought that might lead to confusion and ambiguity.

Comment: I disagree that this question is primarily opinion-based.  There should be a best/accepted practice for setting the version number in this case---one that prevents ambiguity, follows SimVer, and doesn't require every commit to be a release.  With that said, if you want to close it, go ahead.

Comment: Recently I found the [versioneer package](https://github.com/warner/python-versioneer), which provides a great solution. It automatically updates the version number in myproject/__init__.py. Between releases, it appends the shortened git commit id to the previous release tag. Between commits, it also appends "-dirty".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The current recommendations for versioning of Python packages / distributions are summarizied in the [Python Packaging User Guide here](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/?highlight=distributing#standards-compliance-for-interoperability):

```
1.2.0.dev1  # Development release
1.2.0a1     # Alpha Release
1.2.0b1     # Beta Release
1.2.0rc1    # Release Candidate
1.2.0       # Final Release
1.2.0.post1 # Post Release
15.10       # Date based release
23          # Serial release
```

following the recommendations of [draft PEP 440](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/).

Comment: Thanks! That's good information.

Comment: You're welcome.  If you find this (or another) answer to be the most useful, don't forget to mark it as "accepted".

Answer (score 0):

Daniel's not quite right: [Semantic versioning](http://semver.org/) does support pre-releases (emphasis mine):

> (11) Precedence refers to how versions are compared to each other when ordered. Precedence MUST be calculated by separating the version into major, minor, patch and pre-release identifiers in that order (Build metadata does not figure into precedence). Precedence is determined by the first difference when comparing each of these identifiers from left to right as follows: Major, minor, and patch versions are always compared numerically. Example: 1.0.0 < 2.0.0 < 2.1.0 < 2.1.1. *When major, minor, and patch are equal, a pre-release version has lower precedence than a normal version. Example: 1.0.0-alpha < 1.0.0. Precedence for two pre-release versions with the same major, minor, and patch version MUST be determined by comparing each dot separated identifier from left to right until a difference is found as follows: identifiers consisting of only digits are compared numerically and **identifiers with letters or hyphens are compared lexically in ASCII sort order**. Numeric identifiers always have lower precedence than non-numeric identifiers. A larger set of pre-release fields has a higher precedence than a smaller set, if all of the preceding identifiers are equal. Example: 1.0.0-alpha < 1.0.0-alpha.1 < 1.0.0-alpha.beta < 1.0.0-beta < 1.0.0-beta.2 < 1.0.0-beta.11 < 1.0.0-rc.1 < 1.0.0.*

Answer (score -2):

If you're pushing code that isn't "released", you're not following semantic versioning. With SemVer, every update is a release: either a minor release - 2.**1**.0 - in the case of new backwards-compatible functionality, or a patch - 2.1.**1** - in the case of a bug fix.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I agree with you. SemVer doesn't have anything to say about pushing updates to a working branch before creating a release. It talks about how releases should be named, and allows for pre-releases, but at least in my reading of it, it doesn't say that *every* code change requires a new release...